# Frobenius identity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, geodesics

I am studying null geodesic generators and came across the following paragraph under the heading Frobenius identity in which ℓ and $\nabla u$ are normal vector fields to null hypersurface:

$ℓ = −e^ρ ∇u$, or, in index notation, $ℓ_{\alpha}= −e^{\rho} \nabla_{\alpha}u$. Taking the covariant derivative, we get
$∇_{α}ℓ_{β} = −e^ρ∇_{α}ρ∇_{β}u − e^ρ∇_{α}∇_{β}u = ∇_{α}ρ ℓ_{β} − e^ρ∇_{α}∇_{β}u$

 Use Anti-symmetrize and the torsion-free property of ∇ (i.e. $∇_α∇_βu − ∇_β∇_αu = 0)$, we get

 $∇_αℓ_β − ∇_βℓ_α = ∇_αρ ℓ_β − ∇_βρ ℓ_α$

I understand every step except the last equation. Can someone explain how to use anti-symmetric property and torsion free to get the last equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you don't understand, as you've essentially written the answer out already?

Taking the antisymmetric part of $\nabla_{\alpha} \ell_{\beta}$, which you wrote the expression for, immediately gives

\begin{align}
2\nabla_{[\alpha} \ell_{\beta]} &= 2 \ell_{[\beta} \nabla_{\alpha]} \rho - 2 e^{\rho} \nabla_{[\alpha} \nabla_{\beta]} u
\end{align}
The last term vanishes because, as you said, for a torsion-free connection $\nabla_{[\alpha} \nabla_{\beta]} u =0$. Therefore only the first term survives.